# Disposable Email API for Selenium automated testing

Tags: java, email, api, user-interface

I am looking to implement an Email API for my UI automated tests written in Java with Selenium.

Are there any recommendations of an email client in order to do this?

From what i found in my research so far, there is mail7 - but their api documentation wasn’t working for some reason, nada api email, or mailslurp.

Thank you for any suggestion you may have

Comment: Do you mean that you want to test that your application has sent emails and that the email content is correct?

Comment: Are you looking for a hosted service or something you can run on your own computer(s)?

Comment: Hi @Moshe, I am looking for a hosted service, and yes I want to test / or check the email content that has the required data.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used it myself, but I know a number of other developers who are very happy with [Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/).

Mailtrap is specifically designed to do exactly what you want:

- Accept emails from your application (via SMTP)
- Provides an API for you to retrieve the email content

Mailtrap provides many other features, such as checking spam scores of your test emails, sharing test emails with other developers in your team, and more.

There are multiple plans available, including a free plan that allows up to 500 emails per month to a single inbox. Paid plans offer more message capacity, faster sending, sending email to multiple mailboxes, and additional features.

Answer (score 0):

I always used Mailhog for that.
https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog

It has webpage interface and API.

For example, start it in a docker and pass the container name to your web app SMTP settings.

Though not sure why they have so many Github Issues today. Maybe got too popular. I hope they'll catch up.

Comment: I use Mailhog too, and I highly recommend it, but the comments on the question say that a hosted service is desired.